The relationship between $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{b_n}{a_n}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{b_1+\cdots +b_n}{a_1+\cdots+a_n}$
Let $a_n$ and $b_n$ be non-constant positive sequences. Given that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{b_n}{a_n}$ converges, I am curious about the convergence/divergence of the following series:
$$
\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{b_1+\cdots +b_n}{a_1+\cdots +a_n}
$$
I hypothesize that it is likely convergent, as there are sequences that seem to support this conjecture, but I am not certain.
I've explored one avenue, aiming to find a constant $k$ such that
$$
\frac{b_1+\cdots+b_n}{a_1+\cdots +a_n} \leq k\frac{b_n}{a_n}
$$
Unfortunately, I have not succeeded in this endeavor, as I have been unable to locate potentially useful inequalities. Throughout this process, I assumed that $a_n$ is monotonically increasing; if this is not the case, a rearrangement could yield a new sequence whose convergence properties mirror those of the original.
I also try to use the O'Stolz theorem:
$$
\lim _{n \to \infty}\frac{b_1+\cdots+b_n}{a_1+\cdots +a_n}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{b_n}{a_n}$$
But it doesn't mean they are infinitesimals of the same order
My questions are as follows:

How should I proceed to resolve this issue? Should I resort to Cauchy's convergence criterion, or should I continue along my current line of thinking?
What implications does this conclusion carry?Is the O'Stolz theorem that involves the concept of derivatives useful in this context?
Are there any fascinating inequalities that could aid in addressing this problem?

I would be immensely grateful for any assistance or insights you might provide. Thank you very much!

Let $a_n=\dfrac{1}{2^n}$ and $b_n=\dfrac{1}{4^n}$. Then $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{b_n}{a_n} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n}<\infty$ and the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{b_1+b_2+\ldots+b_n}{a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_n}$ diverges since $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{b_1+b_2+\ldots+b_n}{a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_n} = \frac{\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n}{\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n} = \frac{\frac{1}{3}}{1} = \frac 13 \neq 0.$$

Thank you! Due to my carelessness, I only tested the common p-series and thought the problem wouldn't be that simple, haha. Thank you so much!

If $\sum a_n$ diverges then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{b_1+b_2+\ldots+b_n}{a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{b_n}{a_n} = 0$ by Cesaro-Stolz. It would be interesting to know if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{b_1+b_2+\ldots+b_n}{a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_n}$ converges under that additional condition.

If the series  $\sum a_n$ is  convergent then  $\sum {b_1+b_2+\ldots +b_n\over a_1+a_2+\ldots +a_n}$ is divergent, independently of the sequence $b_n$ as $$
{b_1+b_2+\ldots +b_n\over a_1+a_2+\ldots +a_n}> {b_1\over \sum a_n} $$
The claim does not hold also in the case  when  $a_n$ is nonicreasing. Indeed
$${b_1+b_2+\ldots +b_n\over a_1+a_2+\ldots +a_n}>{b_1\over na_1}$$  so the series $\sum {b_1+b_2+\ldots +b_n\over a_1+a_2+\ldots +a_n}$ diverges independently of the sequence $b_n.$
In both cases, given $a_n$ we get   $\sum {b_n\over a_n}<\infty$ for $b_n=2^{-n}a_n.$

Thank you! I understand now, such a conclusion is very interesting!
